# Application insight not showing all data

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am using Application Insights in a Console app. It sends telemetry data to AI, but only a handfull of the data shows up in the portal. What could this be? Here is an example of a record that never shows up. (Gotten from VS Output window)

> Application Insights Telemetry:
>   {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.261308a6f9424edfa10a1fd921e5e963.Exception","time":"2015-10-06T09:42:32.6589782+02:00","iKey":"261308a6-f942-4edf-a10a-1fd921e5e963","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"1.2.0.5639","ai.user.id":"c","ai.session.id":"58923b9e-fa43-474f-b491-b494ab724f03","ai.device.osVersion":"Microsoft
>   Windows NT
>   6.2.9200.0","ai.device.roleInstance":"CWB-XPS","ai.application.ver":"Unknown","ai.device.type":"PC","ai.device.id":"CWB-XPS","ai.device.oemName":"Dell
>   Inc.","ai.device.model":"XPS
>   2720","ai.device.network":"Ethernet","ai.device.language":"nb-NO"},"data":{"baseType":"ExceptionData","baseData":{"ver":2,"handledAt":"UserCode","properties":{"Message":"GuardSystems
>   - TESTER EXCEPTION","Exeption":"System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.\r\n   at
>   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)\r\n
>   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style,
>   NumberFormatInfo info)\r\n   at System.Int32.Parse(String s)\r\n   at
>   SafeFinans.GuardSystems.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Visual
>   Studio
>   Online\SafeFinans\SafeFinans.GuardSystems\SafeFinans.GuardSystems\Program.cs:line
>   23\r\n   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, String[] args)\r\n   at
>   System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, String[] args)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()\r\n 
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)\r\n
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)\r\n   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(Executio","CallerType":"SafeFinans.GuardSystems.Program","CallerName":"CurrentDomain_UnhandledException","DeveloperMode":"true"},"exceptions":[{"id":2389992,"typeName":"System.FormatException","message":"Input
>   string was not in a correct
>   format.","hasFullStack":true,"parsedStack":[{"level":0,"method":"System.Number.StringToNumber","assembly":"mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"},{"level":1,"method":"System.Number.ParseInt32","assembly":"mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"},{"level":2,"method":"System.Int32.Parse","assembly":"mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"},{"level":3,"method":"SafeFinans.GuardSystems.Program.Main","assembly":"SafeFinans.GuardSystems,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null","fileName":"C:\Visual Studio
>   Online\SafeFinans\SafeFinans.GuardSystems\SafeFinans.GuardSystems\Program.cs","line":23},{"level":4,"method":"System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly","assembly":"mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"},{"level":5,"method":"System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly","assembly":"mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"},{"level":6,"method":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly","assembly":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"},{"level":7,"method":"System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context","assembly":"mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"},{"level":8,"method":"System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal","assembly":"mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"},{"level":9,"method":"System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run","assembly":"mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"},{"level":10,"method":"System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run","assembly":"mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"},{"level":11,"method":"System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart","assembly":"mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"}]}]}}}

But somehow this is visible in the protal

> Application Insights Telemetry:
>   {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.261308a6f9424edfa10a1fd921e5e963.Exception","time":"2015-10-06T09:48:33.2193133+02:00","iKey":"261308a6-f942-4edf-a10a-1fd921e5e963","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"1.2.0.5639","ai.user.id":"c","ai.session.id":"9e90e2a4-91f0-4a5e-962b-d5cef36cb217","ai.device.osVersion":"Microsoft
>   Windows NT
>   6.2.9200.0","ai.device.roleInstance":"CWB-XPS","ai.application.ver":"Unknown","ai.device.type":"PC","ai.device.id":"CWB-XPS","ai.device.oemName":"Dell
>   Inc.","ai.device.model":"XPS
>   2720","ai.device.network":"Ethernet","ai.device.language":"nb-NO"},"data":{"baseType":"ExceptionData","baseData":{"ver":2,"handledAt":"UserCode","properties":{"Message":"GuardSystems
>   - Feil","Exeption":"System.InvalidOperationException: An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute
>   URI or BaseAddress must be set.\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClient.PrepareRequestMessage(HttpRequestMessage
>   request)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
>   HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetAsync(Uri
>   requestUri, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetAsync(String
>   requestUri)\r\n   at
>   SafeFinans.GuardSystems.Program.d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Visual
>   Studio
>   Online\SafeFinans\SafeFinans.GuardSystems\SafeFinans.GuardSystems\Program.cs:line
>   51","CallerType":"SafeFinans.GuardSystems.Program+d__3","CallerName":"MoveNext","DeveloperMode":"true"},"exceptions":[{"id":4463106,"typeName":"System.InvalidOperationException","message":"An
>   invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an
>   absolute URI or BaseAddress must be
>   set.","hasFullStack":true,"parsedStack":[{"level":0,"method":"System.Net.Http.HttpClient.PrepareRequestMessage","assembly":"System.Net.Http,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"},{"level":1,"method":"System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsync","assembly":"System.Net.Http,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"},{"level":2,"method":"System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetAsync","assembly":"System.Net.Http,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"},{"level":3,"method":"System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetAsync","assembly":"System.Net.Http,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"},{"level":4,"method":"SafeFinans.GuardSystems.Program+d__3.MoveNext","assembly":"SafeFinans.GuardSystems,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null","fileName":"C:\Visual Studio
>   Online\SafeFinans\SafeFinans.GuardSystems\SafeFinans.GuardSystems\Program.cs","line":51}]}]}}}

Comment: - Is your console app shutting down after the exception? It may not have enough time to send data out - Can you use Fiddler and check if data is successfully sent out?

Comment: I'll try to extend the runtime and check. Thanks.